# Provide a mathematical proof that if a random variable $X \le c$, then the expectation of it is also less than $c$, i.e. $E[X] \le c$.

Tags: probability

I was trying to prove this for the given problem:

> We find an upper bound on the variance of a random variable with
> values in a finite interval. Let $X$ be a random variable taking values
> in the finite interval $[0, c]$. You may assume that $X$ is discrete,
> though this is not necessary for this problem.

Really, I want to manipulate the fact that $X\leq c$, to show $E[X] \leq c$.

I was able to use the givens to show that $E[X^2] \leq c E[X]$

I began by establishing that we have some $X$ in the interval $[0,c]$, $c > 0$ as long as that interval contains more than just $0$ (c is not just 0).
So then $0 \leq X \leq c$

I subtracted x from everything and established that $-X \leq 0 \leq c-X$

so $c-x$ must be greater than or equal to $0$, and $x$ is greater than or equal to $0$ (by assumption)

so I got that $E[X]$ is also greater than or equal to $0$, and so is $E[c-X]$

and was able to conclude that $0 \leq E[X] \leq c$

However, I received feedback that I'm missing a step and I should have proven mathematically that if $X \leq c$ then $E[X] \leq c$. I'm not sure how to fit this in or if my approach was wrong. Could anyone provide any help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of expectation?  Do you know $EX$ defined as an integral? Do you know basic properties of integrals in Measure Theory?

Comment: Generally, if $X$ has an expectation and $X \ge 0$ then $EX \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Discrete (finite) case: let $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$ be all the possible values of the random variables, with $p_1, p_2,\ldots, p_n$ their corresponding probabilities.  We are given that $\max{v_i}\leq c$.
Let
Now  the definition says $E(X)= v_1p_1+v_2p_2+...+v_np_n$
Replacing $v_i$ by their maximum we get an inequality:

$E(X) \leq c(p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_n)= c.1 =c$ .

Now proof for continuous case is got by replacing the summation by integration